# String comparison in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

There is a huge set of data in two columns. I have to print whether the two strings are matching or not into a third column as match/not match.

```
For example-  YES & YeS match
              yes & YES match
              ye2 & yes No match & so on
```

I have been doing this manually, checking values in each column then writing as match/no match. Would appreciate some help to make the process automated.

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/284022/comparing-two-strings-in-excel) give you the answer? To sum up, if you just put `=EXACT(A1,B1)` in `C1` and copy down to you'll get the boolean value for whether or not they match, without having to use VBA. To  get match / not match, just put that boolean into an `IF`-statement.

Comment: @eirikdaude i have tried this EXACT statement, for cases like YES & yEs it gives me value as false although these 2 strings are equal.

Comment: Does `=A1=B1` work? It seems to do when I test it, while `EXACT` gives me the same results as for you. If it works I'll write my comments up as an answer and delete the comments.

Comment: If you want to match regardless of case, convert both cells with `UPPER`. So `=UPPER(A1)=UPPER(B1)` will return true or false.

Comment: A simple equality test will not be case-sensitive as a formula so there is no need for case conversion here.

Comment: If you want to do this in VBA you would use `StrComp()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need VBA to do this, but if yes then you can simply write an UDF specifying (on top of the module) that you're using the [Compare text](http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/12/01/case-in-sensitive-string-compare-vba/) option.

```
Option Compare Text
Public Function compareText(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As String

    If str1 = str2 Then
        compareText = "Match"
    Else
        compareText = "Do not match"
    End If

End Function
```

Once this is added, say you have the data in cells `A1` and `B1`, then you simply add into the cell `C1` the formula `=compareText(A1,B1)` and you scroll it down for the other values.

Please note that this is the most efficient approach, since the `Option Compare Text` will perform a binary comparison of the strings (not having to convert to `UPPER` any string before comparing, something that would affect performance if the amount of data is really huge as you say).